# What does "dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration" actually do?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is it possible to script what `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` actually do?

I always make the same selections, so it would be very nice, if I could do it without any user interaction.

Comment: fyi: /var/lib/dpkg/info/keyboard-configuration.postinst

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seed your options with `debconf` and run `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.

**man debconf-set-selections(1)**:

```
NAME
       debconf-set-selections - insert new default values into the debconf database

SYNOPSIS
        debconf-set-selections file
        debconf-get-selections | ssh newhost debconf-set-selections
```

This shows your current settings:

```
$ debconf-show keyboard-configuration
  keyboard-configuration/modelcode: pc105
  keyboard-configuration/unsupported_config_options: true
  keyboard-configuration/unsupported_config_layout: true
  keyboard-configuration/toggle: No toggling
  ....
```